# mongoose: remove operation - see the output of it

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm performing `remove` operation from collection called `userModel`.

I need to see the IDs of the removed documents in order to take more actions in other collections as well.

This is what i'm doing:

```
userModel.remove(myQuery, function (err, result) {...})
```

In the `result` I only see the number of documents removed.

How can I also see their IDs?

Comment: I don't think you can with just `Model.remove()`. You might need to use the `Model.find()` and multiple `document.remove()` approach.